# Dynamics AX 2012 Binary-Kernel Wizard install not show mandatory prerequisites

Tags: binary, kernel, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm installing Binary Dynamics AX 2012 update, but I cannot to continue, because I need mandatory prerequisites.

The wizard not show me which mandatory update are needed.
I have this screen:
[image]

I NEED a screen like this
[image]

I don't know why.
Someone have an idea how can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You can check the log of the installation if it contains further hints. In a default installation, it is located at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Dynamics AX\Dynamics AX Setup Logs. Could you [edit] the KB number of the update into your question? The [system requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11094) might also offer a hint what is missing.

Comment: Thanks @FH Inway , thanks for your reply. I don't have the log in folder path.

Comment: In the step `Select application updates`, did you make sure to choose things to apply? Are you doing `binary` or `application` or both updates?

Comment: @Alex Kwitny we solved with your help, in other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58666981/cannot-install-dynamics-ax-2012-error-opendatabase)

Comment: We solved by other question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58666981/cannot-install-dynamics-ax-2012-error-opendatabase Thanks.