# Cannot Install Dynamics ax 2012 - error OpenDatabase

Tags: installation, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm try to install Dynamics AX 2012, but I got this error:
[image]

Do you have any idea how can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a bootleg installer or something? It looks like you're not even to the install wizard yet, but you're at the "launcher" style screen.

This shouldn't be necessary, but just in case, re-download the install, make sure to unblock it if needed (Right click, properties, unblock), and retry it on a few different machines (your laptop?) to see if you get past the error...you shouldn't need to complete the full install wherever you decide to try it, just get past the error.

And it looks like you're doing 2012...they have 2012 R2 & R3...so make sure you've downloaded the correct installer.